# What is the most efficient way to redirect 1000 pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I know this question has been asked in many different ways, but I have not been able to find a question or answer exactly like mine.

I have almost 1,000 pages that need to be redirected. There is NO pattern from old page to new page. I already have all of the pages mapped out where they need to redirect in a spreadsheet. These redirects will be happening on WordPress installation.

My biggest concern is performance. I do not want the websites load time to be affected because of the way I have set the redirects up, should I even be concerned?

**Some example of redirects are:**

```
OLD PAGE                    NEW PAGE
/some-page/                 /this-is-a-new-page/
/page/8/                    /another-new-page/
/this/page/is/unique/       /new-unique-page/internal-page/
/i-could-go-on-forever/     /but-i-wont/
```

**I have temporarily set them all up like this in `.htaccess`:**

```
Redirect 301 /some-page/ /this-is-a-new-page/
Redirect 301 /page/8/ /another-new-page/
Redirect 301 /this/page/is/unique/ /new-unique-page/internal-page/
Redirect 301 /i-could-go-on-forever/ /but-i-wont/
```

**My questions are:**

1. Should I just leave the redirects how I current have them set in my `.htaccess` file?
2. Does the order/sorting of the redirects matter?
3. Is there a completely different way I could/should go about doing these redirects?

Comment: Unlikely to make a big difference, but a [rewrite map](http://chrisadams.me.uk/2010/05/24/making-sense-of-rewritemaps-in-apache/) might be feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a WordPress plugin to define what you wish to do since all the page are by default redirected to the WordPress controller anyway?

http://wordpress.org/plugins/404-redirected/

- Get list of 404 URLs as they happen inside the admin panel
- Easily redirect 404 URLs **to existing pages** or choose to ignore the 404 error
- Provides the ability to automatically create redirects based on the URL the visitor was  most likely trying to visit
- Provide visitors with a list of suggested pages on the 404 page when a automatic redirect  can not be made

Seems to have mainly what you need, there is also this one http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ and probably others.

In my view, the advantage of this is that since by default when using WordPress it forces all requests to go to it's index, handling the 404 within itself should be pretty much as effective.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with this method. In the plugin I used, this was what the author said though `Although, I always recommend that if you have over a few dozen redirects, that you look into setting up some .htaccess rules if at all possible, as the draw on the server is a lot less, you can add large numbers of redirects if needed.`

Comment: @doitlikejustin if you want to have a better control over the redirects then you don't have many options even a rewritemap would draw your server resource but that is not available on shared hosting anyway so you would need either a VPS or dedi. Unless you want to make a separated script to that generates all those rules automated for you that you can easily create and recreate it, then again 1000's rules on a high traffic site is a lot to check on a weak or shared server TBH.

Comment: Well luckily this site is on a dedicated server. I will be watching it closely this week, hopefully it's not too affected. If I see a drop in performance I'll look into a rewritemap.